# How to pause an execution of one function to do another function in Python:

Tags: python, aiogram

I have a telgram bot that handles with the text messages and documents and the function that handles with documents will do long operations with the documents. This causes the next problem: until the job with file is done, the bot won't continue handling text messages. Is there a way to "pause" the execution of file_handler function to send a message?

```
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def messages(mes:types.Message):
    if mes == "Hi":
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=mes.chat.id,text="Hi")
    if mes.text=="/start":
        await bot.send_document(mes.from_user.id,document=input_file.InputFile("c.pdf"))

import time
@dp.message_handler(content_types=ContentTypes.DOCUMENT)
async def doc_handler(message:types.Message):
    if document := message.document:
        await document.download(
            destination_file="file.pdf",
        )
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="got file")
        do_with_file("file.pdf")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not "pause" a function, but you can use `asyncio` to run functions concurrently as tasks.

Make sure your long operation function is defined `async`:

```
async def do_with_file(file_name: string):
    ...
```

Launch it as [task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task):

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=ContentTypes.DOCUMENT)
async def doc_handler(message:types.Message):
    if document := message.document:
        await document.download(
            destination_file="file.pdf",
        )
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="got file")
        asyncio.create_task(do_with_file("file.pdf"))
```

Also make sure you create a unique file name for every download so that if one file is still processing while another one is downloading they don't overwrite each other.

You can use the [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module for this, or just append the exact time to the file name.

**EDIT:**
Since using `syncio` did not work, you may try a fully fledged [thread](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/) like so:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=ContentTypes.DOCUMENT)
async def doc_handler(message:types.Message):
    if document := message.document:
        await document.download(
            destination_file="file.pdf",
        )
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="got file")
        file_thread = threading.Thread(target=do_with_file, args=("file.pdf",))
        file_thread.start()
```

Notice the comma after "file.pdf"!
It is not a typo, you need to put any parameters for your function in a `tuple`, and that is how you make a tuple with one element in Python.

Also, to work with threads, don't declare your `do_with_file` function as `async`.
It should stay a regular function, like it is in your current code.

The `Thread` object will run it in parallel, independent of your other code.

Comment: Thanks you, but this didn't help: the bot still doesn't react to the messages while working with file. I in generally don't know much about asychronity, so, if is possible, I would like to see some tutorials

Comment: @NoName might be something specific to Telegram bots, unfortunately I don't have any experience with them. You might have to use threads directly: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html to avoid the `async` event loop. I don't have a specific tutorial to recommend, but there are many videos on youtube if you search for "python asyncio", some explain very nicely how it works.

Comment: Wow, this relly helped! Thank you!